# pthread read/write synchronisation

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

This seems to be a simple task, but it doesnt work. My threadfunction runs in a loop and writes data into an array all the time. But sometimes I want to read this data from my main function. Therefore the read-funtion should ideally pause the thread, read the data, and then resume the thread. But the value that is read is not correct and seems corrupted. Maybe there is something wrong:

thread-fct:

```
void threadfct()
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        data = write_data();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

Function that is called from main-loop should read that data that is written by the thread-function:

```
void read_data()
{
    printf("Daten: %f\n", data[0]);
}
```

Comment: You need to show more context. Do you really read the data without acquiring the mutex first?

Comment: Use std::thread.

Comment: What @FlorianWeimer is implying is that a mutex works only if both threads are trying to take it before entering their critical section

Comment: What about some [MCVE]? `data = write_data();` does not "write data into an array", but change the value of `data` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this change:

```
void read_data()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("Daten: %f\n", data[0]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: I did, but it seems to block the execution of my program.

Comment: @Lemonbonbon then you have locked another mutex?

Comment: So please tell us more about your program, how the threads are created, what you expect to see and what you actually see